# How do I enable the DOM extension in the php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.6

How do I enable the DOM extension in my php.ini file? I am running a Wordpress site and getting a message "Please enable the DOM extension in your PHP configuration".

Do I need to edit the wp-config file or php.ini

Answer (score 22):

You need to install **php-xml**

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

or specific version of the extension

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

and then according to [docs in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php) you have to add

```
extension=dom.so
```

into the php.ini file.

Please note that this extension should be enabled by default. If it's not enabled look for `--disable-dom` option.

Comment: for me I had to `sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml` on ubuntu 16.

Comment: on my CentOS server... i had to add the extension directive as you showed! thank you!   but i also had to copy `/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so` to `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`... the combo is what made it work for me... also... i had to repeat for `simplexml.so` and `xmlwriter.so` to get Authorize.net to work with woocommerce

Comment: adding to @Ibrahim.H 's comment, you obviously have to look for your php version's extentions, f.e. php8.2-xml ... i think the default php version in the packets points at 7.4.33 - and i'm hoping it changes even that soon.

Answer (score 15):

You need to install php-xml.

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Restart your server (here apache).

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And you can check that everything is OK using :

```
php -m
```

Resulting :

```
[PHP Modules]
...
dom < and other relatives modules as xml, xmlreader, SimpleXML...
...

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's work now :)